# How to solve %GTM-E-GDINVALID, Unrecognized Global Directory file format: mumps.gld, expected label: GTCGBDUNX007, found: GTCGBDUNX006?

Tags: mumps

I am getting this error with GT.M:

```
%GTM-E-GDINVALID, Unrecognized Global Directory file format: /home/blah/gt.m/example/mumps.gld, expected label: GTCGBDUNX007, found: GTCGBDUNX006
```

Here is what I did so far:

get the version http://sourceforge.net/projects/fis-gtm/

```
tar -xzf gtm_V55000_linux_i686_pro.tar.gz 

chmod +x semstat2 mupip mumps lke gtmsecshr gtcm_shmclean gtcm_server gtcm_play gtcm_pkdisp gtcm_gnp_server geteuid ftok dse
```

Now we start like this in Bash:

```
mkdir example; cd example
```

...and invoke the mumps from the parent dir:

```
../mumps -r GDE
```

The output is this:

```
%GDE-I-GDUSEDEFS, Using defaults for Global Directory 
 /home/blah/gt.m/example/mumps.gld
```

Now we set the working dir to create the gld file.

```
GDE>  change -s DEFAULT -f=/home/blah/gt.m/gt.m/example/
GDE> exit
```

The output from the command is this :
>%GDE-I-VERIFY, Verification OK
>%GDE-I-GDCREATE, Creating Global Directory file
> /home/blah/gt.m/example/mumps.gld

Now this creates a v6 version of gld, which mupip does not like:

```
strings mumps.gld  | head -1
```

Which contains this string:

```
GTCGBDUNX006H
```

But mupip expects a 7 not a 6!

```
../mupip create

>%GTM-E-GDINVALID, Unrecognized Global Directory file format: >/home/blah/gt.m/example/mumps.gld, expected label: GTCGBDUNX007, found: GTCGBDUNX006
```

If I just edit the file and replace the 6 with a 7,
`../mupip create`.

This works!

Now I have a dat file, and go to gtm to save something :
`GTM>s ^foo("blah")=1`

> %GTM-E-GDINVALID, Unrecognized Global Directory file format: >/home/blah/gt.m/example/mumps.gld, expected label: GTCGBDUNX006, found: GTCGBDUNX007

Oh so that wants a v6, so good thing i backed up the old, one, i replace it .

`GTM>s ^foo("blah")=1`

that works
`GTM>zwr ^foo(*)`

```
>^foo("blah")=1
```

So the data is stored.

Can anyone please explain this? In detail? Why does `mupip` operate with a different version number?

Note, I did not run any other commands, I am just learning and don't want to execute any huge install routines a root that I don't understand.

Comment: I found the problem, it must have been a variable having been set.  gtm_dist and gtmroutines are the culprits. Sorry for taking so long to find this. It turns out to have been an usage error on my problem.   http://fmtyewtk.blogspot.de/2012/08/gtm-install-issue-resolved.html is the resolution post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have GT.M already installed (and I would guess it is an older version) on your system somewhere else and have some environment variable defined for it in your bash/tcsh/*sh environment, or you didn't provide all the step you did to get to that error.

My guess is that you already have GT.M installed somewhere and your above commands uses part of that installation.  You can easily verify this using this command : `env | grep gtm`.

If I follow your steps mentioned above, I get this result :

```
laurent@laurent /tmp/test $ tar -zxf ~/Projects/gtm_V55000_linux_i686_pro.tar.gz
laurent@laurent /tmp/test $ chmod +x semstat2 mupip mumps lke gtmsecshr gtcm_shmclean gtcm_server gtcm_play gtcm_pkdisp gtcm_gnp_server geteuid ftok dse
laurent@laurent /tmp/test $ mkdir example; cd example
laurent@laurent /tmp/test/example $ ../mumps -r GDE
%GTM-E-GTMDISTUNDEF, Environment variable $gtm_dist is not defined
```

So, I as said, you either did something else, or have a different GT.M version already installed and this is why some commands expect different versions of GLD.

Comment: Hi, I did not have gtm installed. I provided all the steps. I will try again on a fresh machine and report back.

Comment: @h4ck3rm1k3 Well, you must be getting the $gtm_dist environment variable from somewhere, and that somewhere is not explained in your question...

Comment: Laurent Parenteau, I will have to check that. I don't think I set the variable. Will redo the test.

Comment: Update : I see you are right. I am redoing the test, will repost.

Comment: OK, you are right! thanks. http://fmtyewtk.blogspot.de/2012/08/gtm-install-issue-resolved.html

Answer (score 3):

In your steps you don't show whether you installed GT.M or not.

That is only the unziped version, first:

```
    chmod 777 configure
    ./configure
```

The installation will produce new files in the `gtm_dist` directory.

Comment: I did not run the configure program, it was pretty scary and runs as root. I just tried to do a minimal unpacking. The question is, why does one program have the version 6 and the other 7 in the same package? is that a bug or what?

Comment: Honestly I have never noticed as I always install gt.m. What I can say of that version is that after running configure you will have no problems. Those kind of errors are usual when you copy files from AIX to Linux for example, and the endian is different or even when you have a GT.M version 5.x and yout try to use database files generated from a GT.M 4.x. Regards

Comment: Well, you can easily verify this yourself. just follow my instructions and you will see the problem. maybe the install routines rebuilds the system. I think this software should be installable without root access ss.

Answer (score 1):

As Bhaskar has noted in your cross post on Hardhats.  Make sure you follow the installation instructions for GT.M.  Instructions can be found in Chapter 2 of the [UNIX Administration and Operations Guide](http://tinco.pair.com/bhaskar/gtm/doc/books/ao/UNIX_manual/index.html)

Comment: that is not answering the question, the question is why two programs in the distro have different release numbers.